# Converting HTML element into array and dealing with null

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using javascript to read an HTML element that contains an array, but I suppose it is just a string version of an array. So I have converted this to a javscript array of integers, however I am having a problem when the the HTML array is empty.

HTML: (empty array)

```
<div id="activelist"> [] </div>
```

HTML: (array contains values)

```
<div id="activelist"> [4, 5] </div>
```

I am using `let activeMachines = document.getElementById("activelist").innerHTML;` in my script to grab the values from the page.

if I `console.log(activeMachines);` It will return `[]` when the array is empty.

if I `console.log(activeMachines);` It will return `[3, 5]` when the array contains values.

Now to process this into a javascript array of integers I use:

```
//trim off the quotes and brackets
activeMachines = activeMachines.slice(2, -2);

//split into different objects
activeMachines = activeMachines.split(', ');

console.log(activeMachines.length);
```

Now the part I can't figure out:

When the array is empty `console.log(activeMachines.length);` will return 1

When the array has a value in it `console.log(activeMachines);` will return 1

when the array has two values in it `console.log(activeMachines);` will return 2

Is there a way to get the `array.length` to be `0` when it is empty? Maybe `.length` is the wrong operator to use?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please add some raw data of `innerHTML` and the wanted outcome.

Comment: I added the HMTL. The outcome is that I want `.length` to return `0` when the array is empty

Comment: "*It will return ["3", "5",]*" - based on your HTML, why would it return quoted values?

Comment: hi Could you please use eval()

Comment: @DavidThomas, you are right, it does not return quotes, I edited my post.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your reasoning for needing to handle arrays in html like this?

Comment: where is the `null` part of the question?

Comment: @charlietfl, that's quite possible! I am using Django to filter my database and return an array to the webpage, then using javascript to process this array further. I did originally use REST and fetch to get all the database entries and filter entirely using javascript, but this ended up being significantly more code. However I am very novice at coding so I'm sure there is an even better solution that I don't know about

Comment: @NinaScholz: The `null` was regarding the empty array. My mistake if that's not the correct wording

Comment: Do a little research into how to pass a django array to javascript. Will involve converting to *JSON* format and is rarely placed inside standard html content elements as you are currently doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and return an array.

```js
function getValue(id) {
    return JSON.parse(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
}

var data = ['activelist0', 'activelist1'].map(getValue);

console.log(data[0].length);
console.log(data[0]);
console.log(data[1].length);
console.log(data[1]);
```

```html
<div id="activelist0"> [] </div>
<div id="activelist1"> [4, 5] </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON.parse, we can parse the innerHTML and get the actual type that you want to evaluate. Ensure you wrap it around in a try catch or else you will run into an error as there is no validator for the content inside the div.

Here's a quick example:

```js
var activeList = document.querySelectorAll('.active-list');
var debug = document.getElementById('debug');

activeList.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  try {
    var arr = JSON.parse(elem.textContent);
    debug.innerHTML += (index + 1) + ' result length is: ' + arr.length + '<br/>';
  } catch (error) {
    debug.innerHTML += (index + 1) + ' error';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="active-list">[4, 5]</div>
<div class="active-list">[1]</div>
<div class="active-list">[]</div>
<div class="active-list">this should invoke an error!</div>
<br/>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One further option:

```
// declaring a named function, using Arrow syntax:
const parseArray = (el) => {

  // retrieving the text content of the current element ('el'),
  // removing any leading and trailing spaces using
  // String.prototype.trim() and then replacing the '['
  // and ']' characters using String.prototype.replace,
  // along with a regular expression; replacing those
  // characters with an empty string:
  let values = el.textContent.trim().replace(/\[|]/g, ''),

    // if the length of the modified String is zero then we
    // return an empty Array; otherwise w split the the
    // String using String.prototype.split(), to split
    // the String into an Array:
    result = values.length === 0 ? [] : values.split(',');

  // logging the result:
  console.log(result);

  // returning the result to the calling context:
  return result;
}

// using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all <li>
// elements on the page, and then calling NodeList.prototype.forEach()
// in order to call the named function (note the deliberate lack of
// parentheses on the function name):
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(parseArray);
```

```js
const parseArray = (el) => {
  let values = el.textContent.trim().replace(/\[|]/g, ''),
    result = values.length === 0 ? [] : values.split(',');
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(parseArray);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>[]</li>
  <li>["1","2","3"]</li>
  <li>[a,b,,d,e]</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/0eusbp4y/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

Mixing data model with representation is a bad practice. A better way is to separate the two. For example:

```
var myData = [1,2,3];

function renderData(data)
{
  return data.join(", ");
}
```

Thus, you can manipulate `myData` and always get the right result regardless of how data is rendered.